# Dynamically insert code to custom post type loop

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, loop

I need to display post from custom post type name "film", from a specific taxonomy "Horror."
Everything work fine when I type the taxonomy directly like this:

```
    <?php  $blog = array(
    'post_type'         => 'film',
    'catfilm' => 'Horror',                      
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    =>4,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
     );
    ?>
```

I need to insert dynamically the taxonomy with CMB2, so I change the code like this, but no luck. The post failed to appear:
My CMB2 function:

```
$cmb_tvseries->add_field( array(
    'name'        => esc_html__( 'type the category', 'cmb2' ),
    'id'          => 'mytheme_catfilm',
    'type'        => 'text',
) );
```

My loop change to:

```
  <?php $blog = array(
    'post_type'         => 'film',
    'catfilm' => '<?php echo ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "mytheme_catfilm", true ) ); ?>',                       
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    =>4,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    );
    ?>
```

I am newbie on php. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable outside the array and then pass it to the array:

```
<?php 
$catfilm = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "mytheme_catfilm", true );
$blog = array(
    'post_type'         => 'film',
    'catfilm'           => $catfilm,                       
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => 4,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    );
?>
```

Comment: It's work. Thank you very much.